# Use of 'this' within a class definition

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In one of the [Boost.Asio tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html), they call, within the constructor, an async wait on the timer.

```
Printer(boost::asio::io_service& io) : timer_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)), count_(0) {
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Printer::print, this));
}
```

`print`is a member function defined by

```
void print()
{
    if (count_ < 5)
    {
      std::cout << count_ << std::endl;
      ++count_;

      timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
      timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&printer::print, this));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why **this** is bound to the `print`function since the `print`function doesn't take any argument (not even an error code)

In the code sample, this is justified by *Since all non-static class member functions have an implicit this parameter, we need to bind this to the function.*

But I don't understand the *need* to bind  *this* to the function.

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Q: What does `count_` refer to if you don't have an instance of `Printer` at hand?

Comment: It's because the method is an instance method and needs binding to the instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Member functions are invoked **on an object**. That's why there's an implicit `this` parameter. You cannot call a member function without a valid instance of the class.

`bind` needs you to pass the object on which the member is invoked, for that very reason.

Comment: But as far as I know, a member functions are invoked on an object as follow : `object.memberFunction()`
Do you mean that we can also call such function as follow `memberFunction(object)` ? If not, I don't understand the syntax of passing the object itself as an argument of its own member function.

Comment: @PierreP. - Who said `bind` calls it as `memberFunction(object)`? It contains logic to resolve such calls at compile time. It will call it using member access syntax.

Comment: Ok I get it! Binding `this` to the member function `print` will ensure that whenever `print` is called, it will be called from `this` instance. Is that right?

Comment: @PierreP. - Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`print` function is a non-static member function of class `Printer`. Just like all other non-static member functions it receives an implicit `this` parameter that allows it to access class instance fields (`timer_` and `count_` in this case). Functor that can be called by boost times is limited to have no parameters, and that is where `bind` comes to the rescue providing `operator ()` that to be called by timer and then internally calling `Printer::print` with stored `this` pointer.